# Automaticng An Array Of Images

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I need to automate an array of traffic lights, so they go from red to red-amber to green then to amber all by itself, any help?

This is the code I have now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 20px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                display: inline-block;
                min-width: 100px;
                min-height: 30px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #FFF;
            }
        </style>

        <body>
            <img id="light" src="Traffic_Light_Red.png">
            <button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Click to Change The Light Sequence</button>
            <script>
                var list = [
                    "Traffic_Light_Red.png",
                    "Traffic Light Red And Yellow Only.png",
                    "Traffic Light Green Only.png",
                    "Traffic Light Yellow Only.png"
                ];

                var index = 0;

                function changeLights() {
                index = index + 1;

                if (index == list.length) index = 0;

                var image = document.getElementById('light');

                image.src=list[index];
            }

            </script>
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to provide working source to these images.

Comment: Your source code is quite a mess of broken tags...

Answer (score 0):

Provided the list of image filenames translate to valid urls the code should work.

You have two broken tags before the closing `</body>` tag which you should removed:

```
}
</script>
```

But they should not be the cause of the images not appearing.

The following demonstrates the code:

```js
var list = [
  "Traffic_Light_Red.png",
  "Traffic Light Red And Yellow Only.png",
  "Traffic Light Green Only.png",
  "Traffic Light Yellow Only.png"
  ];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
  var image = document.getElementById('light');
  var desc = document.getElementById('description');
  index = index + 1;
  if (index == list.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  
  image.src = list[index];
  // for demo purposes
  desc.innerHTML = image.src;
}
```

```css
#light {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: #fee;
}

button {
  padding: 15px;
}

#description {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img id="light" src="Traffic_Light_Red.png">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Click to Change The Light Sequence</button>

<div id="description"></div>
```